# Uninstall old swift version

Tags: 19.04

I have an old version of swift `swift-4.2.1-RELEASE` on my Ubuntu machine, which I need to uninstall, so that I will be able to install the latest version. But I couldn't find a good article that explains clearly how. I have been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Swift on Ubuntu 19.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142200/)

Comment: @karel how is this a duplicate man i have multiple version of swift installed on machine iam unable to switch between them i need to **UNINSTALLED** on version how can do that?

Comment: Well, here's how it works. The accepted answer explains the location  where swift is installed. Browse to that location and then manually delete the swift directory including everything that's in it. Then reinstall the new version of swift back in the same location, so you don't have to change the existing path to swift.

Comment: @karel i appreciate your help but none of the solution you suggest works for me?

Comment: I guessed that you put swift in the swift directory. What most people would do is say where they installed swift in the question. If you don't put that information in the question then we'll have to guess because it's unclear what you are asking.